# Is there any way on how to download bootstrap templates (with HTML) from the ones they made and shown as examples in ther official website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way I could download the exact custom templates that Bootstrap made? Like the Dashboard, Signin page, Cover page, Carousel page http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/ and more.

Is there a way to do this without manually copying their source codes from the developer tools/inspect element >> resources?

Because even if I download from their customize page (http://getbootstrap.com/customize) it only returns the very basic bootstrap pack-- the bootstrap.js, bootstrap-theme.js, bootstrap.css, glyphicons.. there is no even html template included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap always keeps a Github repo of all the resources whether it be documentation or HTML or CSS or JS.

You can find all their relevant documents and the examples at their [Github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) repo.

The ones you are specifically looking for can be found [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/docs/examples).

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for that! I just realized there is a download link for that in http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download -_- Stupid me, I didnt read the caption. I just clicked the "Download Bootstrap", when in fact I should be clicking "Download source" since it contains the whole pack in their github page.